# Rendering QWidget within QMainWindow

Tags: qt, qt5

I've a `QMainWindow` object which contains central widget (`QAbstractItemView` based one).

I've reimplemented `paintEvent` of central widget and on this event I'm rendering another widget with `QWidget::render`. I've set `targetOffset` parameter of `QWidget::render` to `QPoint(0, 0)`.

I was expecting that widget will be painted at position (0, 0) of central widget but instead it's being painted at position (0, 0) of `QMainWindow` object, so most of it is hidden under menu bar.

Is this normal behaviour? Of course, in my `paintEvent` of central widget I'm using `QPainter` with `viewport()` as argument, so it should paint over my central widget.

**EDIT:**

After some investigations I've decided to fill a bug report for Qt.
[Here it is](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47302)

My current workaround is to render widget into `QPixmap` and then draw this pixmap.

Comment: How are you placing you central widget into the `QMainWindow` instance?

Comment: You can only paint a widget in its own paint event handler (via reimplementation or event filters). You can't paint another widget.

Comment: @peppe: `QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: but I don't paint it, I render it ;) I think it's slightly different situation